# aiohttp throws server disconnected for nasdaq.com

Tags: python, aiohttp

aiohttp seems to be working fine with most website I have used, but not nasdaq. I am trying to follow this `https://stackoverflow.com/a/67641667` and use custom connectors but haven't had any luck so far. is there any other way to find the problem?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid format of user-agent:

```
"user-agent": "Mozilla"
```

As mentioned in [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) this is a correct format:

```
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (<system-information>) <platform> (<platform-details>) <extensions>"
```

So just try replacing your user agent with something like this:

```
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0"
```

Then it should work.

Comment: fixed for a while but the problem is back. more so, using requests module always works. aiohttp has intermittent issues.